# Word order and such for saying complex phrases without verbs in Chinese?

Tags: phrase, preposition

I am starting to understand how to say basic noun phrases and such in Chinese, and have seen [this article](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Chinese_word_order) on Chinese word order, showing word order with verb being something like:

[image]

But how do you organize the words for extremely complex statements (in English) like these?

> - My big brother's potentially precious book **on** the table **below** the TV **by** the bed.
> - That book **at** the store **by** the place **in** the mall **with** the two guards.

You can start adding participles/gerunds (in English), but I don't know if that counts as adding verbs to these structures. But something like this comes to mind:

> - That thing at the place where we **stood** outside all night under the stars.
> - That thing **standing** in the middle of the road with everyone **honking** their horns while they were **stopped** in traffic.

Does that count as a non-verbed noun phrase? I am not really sure what this is structured like in English totally, but how would you do these sentences in Chinese (with Pinyin and ideally a literal English gloss)? I am curious to know mainly how the English prepositions are handled in these verbless phrases. Wondering if there is a preferred or particular word order, or if there are multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: I keep thinking of ways to translate it that simplify the complexity while conveying the same meaning.  I presume you want the answer to have the same complexity if possible so I am waiting to see if someone can do so (most likely yes).

Answer (score 1):

Universal guide: just list them out in general-to-specific order (reverse order of English):

> My big brother's potentially precious book on the table below the TV by the bed.

床边电视下桌子上的我哥哥的珍贵书籍

```
床chuáng边biān电diàn视shì下xià桌zhuō子zi上shàng的de我wǒ哥gē哥ge的de珍zhēn贵guì书shū籍jí
```

> That book at the store by the place in the mall with the two guards.

在那个有两个保安的商场的书籍

```
在zài那nà个gè有yǒu两liǎng个gè保bǎo安ān的de商shāng场chǎng的de书shū
```

> That thing at the place where we stood outside all night under the stars.

那个我们在户外星星下站了一整晚的地方的东西

```
那nà个gè我wǒ们men在zài户hù外wài星xīng星xīng下xià站zhàn了le一yī整zhěng晚wǎn的de地dì方fāng的de东dōng西xī
```

> That thing standing in the middle of the road with everyone honking their horns while they were stopped in traffic.

I can't translate it to a single phrase. Maybe:

立在路中间的, 当交通被停下来时大家都在那按喇叭的东西.

```
lì在zài路lù中zhōng间jiān的de,当dāng交jiāo通tōng被bèi停tíng下xià来lái时shí大dà家jiā都dōu在zài那nà按àn喇lǎ叭bā的de东dōng西xī.
```

Maybe you wanna see how to add more modifier clause, and here I add more to one of your examples:

那个即将退休的 **警察** 在他最倒霉的 **那天** **在警察局** 的审讯室里 **不停地** 当着所有人的面 一边喝咖啡一边 **对**着马上就要崩溃的 **他** 紧张地 **审问了 几个小时**

```
那nà个gè即jí将jiāng退tuì休xiū的de**警jǐng察chá**在zài他tā最zuì倒dǎo霉méi的de**那nà天tiān****在zài警jǐng察chá局jú**的de审shěn讯xùn室shì里lǐ**不bù停tíng地dì**当dāng着zhe所suǒ有yǒu人rén的de面miàn一yī边biān喝hē咖kā啡fēi一yī边biān**对duì**着zhe马mǎ上shàng就jiù要yào崩bēng溃kuì的de**他tā**紧jǐn张zhāng地dì**审shěn问wèn了le几jǐ个gè小xiǎo时shí**
```

I shifted 不停地 and 在警察局 to make it more smooth.

Though these Chinese phrases are valid in grammar, that doesn't mean they sound natural.

I used this tool to quickly add pinyin:

https://www.jcinfo.net/zh-hans/tools/pinyin

Comment: Could you add pinyin and/or an English literal gloss as well?

Comment: The actual translation should be "我哥哥的珍贵书籍在床边电视下的桌子上. "

Comment: @r13 Actually no. The original English is NOT a complete sentence. It is a giant noun phrase around the noun "book". Your Chinese sentence translates to: My big brother's  precious book IS on the table below the TV by the bed. Not the same at all.

Comment: @monalisa "on" is 在..之上. English requires "is" to be grammatically correct, not the case with Chinese. No matter what, a translation needs to be as close to the original as possible, it starts with "My big brother's..."= "我哥哥的..." .

Comment: @r13 I never said your sentence is not grammatical correct. The original English "My big brother's potentially precious book on the table below the TV by the bed" is a PHRASE, not a sentence. Your Chinese rendition is a sentence. It cannot be the same as the original, and therefore NOT a translation. That is my point.

Comment: @r13 Also, a translation needs to convey the same MEANING as the original. It does not need to start with the same thing, or have the same word order as the original. A word-for-word rendition is unlikely to be a good translation.

Comment: @monalisa I consider my sentence reflects the original meaning correctly and made it more readable. I stated my opinion.

Comment: I sure hope the rest of us understand the difference between a sentence and a noun phrase.

Comment: @r3, These phrases are made for grammar demonstration, they should be translated as literally as possible, moreover, the grammar quality should not be changed, otherwise, how do you compare the grammar?